# Regex: Copy first 10 lines from all open documents

Tags: windows, notepad++

I use grepWin and notepad++ for documents. I want to copy first 10 lines from all open documents, for this I made 2 regex:

`\A(?:.*\n){10}`  or  `\A^.*(?:\R.*){10}`

But non of them works in notepad++ of in grepWin. I think I did something wrong, can anyone give me a better regex?

Comment: `^(?:.*\R){10}` matches the 10 first lines from the current file. I don't think it is possible to copy n lines from all open files.

Comment: hello, Toto. Is not very good your regex, because it matches 10+10 lines...so on, not just the first 10 :)

it is very simple to copy n lines from all open documents if you are using grepWin. Just make a regex search, then check the "content" button down on the right.

Answer (score 0):

this is the best solution:

`\A^.*(?:\R.*){10}`

to copy the first 10 lines from a lot of documents, you must use the simple grepWin software. Just search this regex formula, and then check down on right "content" option. You will see selected all the first 10 lines from all documents. You can copy all, deleted, etc..